# Facebooker and graph API, get news feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker

How to get the news feed for a user with Facebooker?

If it is not possible, how can I use the graph api to take advantage of the fact that the user is already logged in with Facebooker, and has a `Facebook_session active`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using the facebook graph API, I highly recommend you check out these two gems: [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) and [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph).

I hope this helps.

Comment: fb_graph has a great sample app (with source code) that can be viewed here http://fbgraphsample.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can using facebook graph API

```
facebook->api("/user/feed");
```

Use facebook latest SDK